# Usar parâmetros do inicio e fim sem usar os do meio. PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Boa noite!

Imaginem que eu tenha uma function com alguns parâmetros setados como null:

```
public function Usuario($Nome = null, $Idade = null, $Sexo = null, $Email = null) {

    $this->Nome = (string) $Nome;
    $this->Idade = (int) $Idade;
    $this->Sexo = (string) $Sexo;
    $this->Email = (string) $Email;

}
```

Vamos supor que quero somente usar o Nome e o Email, o Sexo e Idade não. Como faço isso Quando eu chamar o método?

Comment: Acho que o jeito é: `Usuario("nome", null, null, "email")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php) do PHP:

> "Note que usando argumentos padrão, qualquer padrão deve vir após os argumentos sem padrão: caso contrário, as coisas não funcionarão como esperado."

Ou seja, a única forma de fazer o que você quer fazer é passando os parâmetros já nulos:

```
Usuario("nome", null, null, "email");
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar os parâmetros através de array, isso facilita, principalmente se a quantidade de parâmetros for grande.

```
public function Usuario($dados = array()) {

  $this->Nome = isset($dados["nome"]) ? $dados["nome"] : null;
  $this->Idade = isset($dados["idade"]) ? $dados["idade"] : null;
  $this->Sexo = isset($dados["sexo"]) ? $dados["sexo"] : null;
  $this->Email = isset($dados["email"]) ? $dados["email"] : null;

}

// montando array
$dados = array();
$dados["nome"] = "João";
$dados["idade"] = "20";

// chamando função
Usuario($dados);
```